# Converter para tipo de data 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, datetime, data

Estou com um problema ao tentar modificar o tipo de data que me aparece em duas colunas de uma tabela minha.

Esse aí é o meu código:

```
declare @top10reclamacoes varchar(max)
declare @html varchar(max)
declare @numero_reclamacoes_abertas_mes integer 
declare @numero_reclamacoes_fechadas_mes integer
declare @startofcurrentmonth datetime


  SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, R.Data, 111) AS Data
    FROM Reclamacoes R



SELECT @numero_reclamacoes_abertas_mes = count(*)
FROM Reclamacoes R
WHERE R.Data >= DATEADD(month, -1, @startOfCurrentMonth)


set @html = '<html>
<body>
<font face="verdana" size="6"><b><u><center>INFORMAÇÃO PARA TODA A EMPRESA</center></u></b></font><br>
<br>
<font face ="verdana "size="5"><b><center>Número reclamações abertas este mês:' + convert(varchar(50), @numero_reclamacoes_abertas_mes)

SELECT @numero_reclamacoes_fechadas_mes = count(*)
FROM Reclamacoes R
WHERE R.DataConclusao >= DATEADD(month, -1, @startOfCurrentMonth)
And Tratado = 1

set @html = @html + '<br><br>Número reclamações fechadas este mês:' + convert(varchar(50), @numero_reclamacoes_fechadas_mes)


Select top 10 @html = @html + '<tr><td>' + convert(nvarchar(50), ID) + '</td><td>' + convert(datetime, R.Data) + '</td><td>' + ISNULL(convert(nvarchar(50),DataConclusao) , '') + '</td><td>' + convert(nvarchar(max), Exposicao) + '</td><td>' + convert(nvarchar(50), Tratado) + '</td></tr>' 
From Reclamacoes R 
Order by R.Data ASC

set @html = @html + '</html></table>'

print @html
```

Onde está os campos `R.Data` e `R.DataConclusao`, o formato do tipo de data é `2018-11-27 00:00:00.0000000` e o que eu pretendo é `2018-11-27`.

Alguém me consegue ajudar? Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já descobri o erro.
O erro estaria na parte do código:

```
convert(datetime, R.Data)
ISNULL(convert(nvarchar(50),DataConclusao)
```

E a solução para o mesmo é:

```
convert(char(10), R.Data)
convert(char(10), R.DataConclusao)
```

Agradeço desde já a ajuda do @Sorack, porém a resposta não me ajudou a 100%.

Comment: Você não informou o *estilo*, na conversão; é o terceiro parâmetro da função CONVERT. O resultado então pode variar, dependendo da definição de LANGUAGE.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GETDATE(), 126);
```

Definir o tamanho 10 separa a hora da data.

No link abaixo [**CAST e CONVERT (Transact-SQL) - Estilos de data e hora**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187928.aspx#Anchor_4) da documentação você pode conferir os códigos correspondentes à conversões de data;

Conversões disponíveis:

```
╔═════════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Sem século (AA) ║ Com século (aaaa) ║ Standard                          ║ Entrada/saída (3)                      ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 0 ou 100 (1,2)    ║ Padrão para datetime e            ║ mês dd aaaa hh:miAM (ou PM)            ║
║                 ║                   ║ smalldatetime                     ║                                        ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1               ║ 101               ║ EUA                               ║ 1 = mm/dd/aa                           ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 101 = mm/dd/aaaa                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 3               ║ 103               ║ Britânico/francês                 ║ 3 = dd/mm/aa                           ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 103 = dd/mm/aaaa                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 4               ║ 104               ║ Alemão                            ║ 4 = dd.mm.aa                           ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 104 = dd.mm.aaaa                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 5               ║ 105               ║ Italiano                          ║ 5 = dd-mm-aa                           ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 105 = dd-mm-aaaa                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 6               ║ 106 (1)           ║ -                                 ║ 6 = dd mês aa                          ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 106 = dd mês aaaa                      ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 7               ║ 107 (1)           ║ -                                 ║ 7 = Mês dd, aa                         ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 107 = Mês dd, aaaa                     ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 8               ║ 108               ║ -                                 ║ hh:mi:ss                               ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 9 ou 109          ║ Padrão + milissegundos            ║ mês dd aaaa hh:mi:ss:mmmAM (ou PM)     ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 10              ║ 110               ║ EUA                               ║ 10 = mm-dd-aa                          ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 110 = mm-dd-aaaa                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 11              ║ 111               ║ JAPÃO                             ║ 11 = aa/mm/dd                          ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 111 = aaaa/mm/dd                       ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 12              ║ 112               ║ ISO                               ║ 12 = aammdd                            ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ 112 = aaaammdd                         ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 13 ou 113         ║ Padrão Europa + milissegundos     ║ dd mês aaaa hh:mi:ss:mmm (24h)         ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 14              ║ 114               ║ -                                 ║ hh:mi:ss:mmm(24h)                      ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 20 or 120 (2)     ║ ODBC canônico                     ║ aaaa-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)               ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 21 or 121 (2)     ║ ODBC canônico (com milissegundos) ║ aaaa-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)               ║
║                 ║                   ║ padrão para hora, data, datetime2 ║                                        ║
║                 ║                   ║ e datetimeoffset                  ║                                        ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 126 (4)           ║ ISO8601                           ║ aaaa-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm (sem espaços)  ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║                                        ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ Observação: Quando o valor de          ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ milissegundos (mmm) for 0, o valor de  ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ milissegundos não é exibido. Por       ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ exemplo, o valor                       ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ '2012-11-07T18:26:20.000' é exibido    ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ como '2012-11-07T18:26:20'.            ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 127(6, 7)         ║ ISO8601 com fuso horário Z.       ║ aaaa-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ (sem espaços) ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║                                        ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ Observação: Quando o valor de          ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ milissegundos (mmm) for 0, o valor de  ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ milissegundos não é exibido. Por       ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ exemplo, o valor                       ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ '2012-11-07T18:26:20.000' é exibido    ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ como '2012-11-07T18:26:20'.            ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 130 (1, 2)        ║ Hijri (5)                         ║ dd mmm aaaa hh:mi:ss:mmmAM             ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║                                        ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ Neste estilo, mon representa uma       ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ representação unicode Hijri de vários  ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ tokens do nome completo do mês. Este   ║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ valor não será renderizado corretamente║
║                 ║                   ║                                   ║ em uma instalação US padrão do SSMS.   ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ -               ║ 131 (2)           ║ Hijri (5)                         ║ dd/mm/aaaa hh:mi:ss:mmmAM              ║
╚═════════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

- (1) esses valores de estilo retornam resultados não determinísticos. Incluem todos os estilos (aa) (sem século) e um subconjunto de estilos (aaaa) (com século).
- (2) Os valores padrão (style 0 ou 100, 9 ou 109, 13 ou 113, 20 ou 120, e 21 ou 121) sempre retornam o século (yyyy).
- (3) entrada quando você converte em datetime; saída quando você converter dados de caractere.
- (4) projetado para uso de XML. Para conversão de datetime ou smalldatetime dados de caracteres de formato de saída é conforme descrito na tabela anterior.
- (5) Hijri é um sistema de calendário com muitas variações. SQL Server usa o algoritmo kuwaitiano.

Comment: e como ponho isso em prática? pode me ajudar? blz

Comment: @MiguelMeireles testa o código que eu coloquei na resposta que você vai entender como usar

Comment: agradecido pela sua ajuda, valeu.

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode utilizar o `FORMAT`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as DataFormatada
```

Comment: eu já tentei fazer isso, mas acontece que depois só me aparece a coluna da data formatada, o resto do código desaparece

Comment: Cara, acho que seu codigo que esta errado.

Comment: Pois, e eu não sei onde. o código que eu tenho, dá, mas foi me pedido que eu alterasse a hora para aquela, e agora não estou a achar jeito de resolver isso.

Comment: O codigo que voce postou funciona? Pq eu tentei rodar ele local aqui e nao tive sucesso. :(

Comment: É normal não funcionar no seu cara, este código é para minha empresa, você não tem as tabelas criadas que eu tenho. mas já arranjei a solução para isso, espero que esteja clara